# Log Jenkins actions outside of Jenkins logs

Tags: java, jenkins, logging

I want to log some INFO messages in a separate file outside var/jenkins/logs (default log location of Jenkins) but I wasn't able to find any working examples.

Logging into Jenkins logs is easy:

```
static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger([YOUR_CLASS_NAME].class.getName());
LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, [MESSAGE]);
```

but I'm not sure how I can log messages in a separate file.

Any help is much appreciated!

***Addendum after response***

The context from which I want to log is within a custom plugin that I've wrote where I basically overwrite the default comparator in Jenkins with my custom one. Based on certain criteria, jobs are seen as more prioritary than others in the build queue.

```
@Override
public int compare(Queue.BuildableItem lhs, Queue.BuildableItem rhs) {
    if (shouldBePrioritized(lhs) && !shouldBePrioritized(rhs)) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "[BQP] Comparing " + lhs.task.getName() + "and " + rhs.task.getName() + ". Result: " + lhs.task.getName());
        return -1;
    }
    if (shouldBePrioritized(rhs) && !shouldBePrioritized((lhs))) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "[BQP] Comparing " + lhs.task.getName() + "and " + rhs.task.getName() + ". Result: " + rhs.task.getName());
        return 1;
    }
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "[BQP] Comparing " + lhs.task.getName() + "and " + rhs.task.getName() + ". Result: equal");
    return super.compare(lhs, rhs);
}
```

I currently use this LOGGER.log() which logs the comparisons into Jenkins logs, but I would like to log the comparisons in a separate file on the VM that the Docker container running Jenkins is located, but I believe that's beyond the scope of the question. For now, it's ok if I manage to log that info in a file within the container of Jenkins.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this help: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Logging

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a custom Handler for the Logger you get.

```
static final LOGGER = createLogger();

private static Logger createLogger() {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());
    FileHandler handler = new FileHandler("/tmp/mylog.log", 1024 * 1024, 10, true); // You can use any variable as a first argument, including some constants from other classes too!
    handler.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
    logger.addHandler(handler);
    return logger;
}
```

The documentation [explains this here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Logging#Logging-MakinglogsavailableoutsideofthewebUI) (in Groovy, but the syntax is moslty same in Java, except the semicolons the end of the line).

If you update your question with the context where you want to write logs (plugin? Custom Hook?) then maybe we can help you to get more specific answer to your question. Also, please reveal some of your real code and tell us where you stuck.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Actually I'm more familiar with Groovy so that shouldn't be a problem. I've updated the question.